# What does it mean that `gen_server` dodges auto-connections on sends but not suspends?

Tags: erlang

The `gen_server` implementation has this fun [little function](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/afb91b3fc36e57997364f20abaef9d4528113e91/lib/stdlib/src/gen_server.erl#L398):

```
do_send(Dest, Msg) ->
    case catch erlang:send(Dest, Msg, [noconnect]) of
        noconnect ->
            spawn(erlang, send, [Dest,Msg]);
        Other ->
            Other
    end.
```

The entry for `erlang:send/3` says of the `noconnect` option

> If the destination node would have to be auto-connected before doing the send, noconnect is returned instead.

The function here avoids the delay in setting up a connection between nodes by forcing a spawned process to do the waiting. Clever!

There's another option to `erlang:send/3`, `nosuspend`:

> If the sender would have to be suspended to do the send, nosuspend is returned instead.

Per, `erlang:send_nosuspend/2` the sender will be suspended if the connection is overloaded. Why would not `gen_server` wish to pull the same trick to avoid suspension of the sending process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does this when `Dest` is on another erlang node. It first tries to send the message *without* forcing a connection to be set-up if the nodes aren't connected, the `[noconnect]` option. If this can be done then `erlang:send/3` sends the message. If this can't be done then we spawn a process which does a send which waits for the connection to be set up. Setting up a connection between two nodes can take time. This is, of course, so we don't sit and wait unnecessarily for the send.

**EDIT:**
The `gen_server` doesn't handle the `nosuspend` case at all, it just worries about the case where sending a message to a remote process could take time because of the need to wait for a connection to be set up. In which case a process is spawned so we can go on. This does not change the semantics. The `nosuspend` does a more complex handling of eventual network problems which would probably need more complex handling than should be provided in a standard API.

Comment: I think the question is, why there is not used `[nosuspend]` which should have same effect or we understand documentation wrong.

Comment: Thanks, Robert! I'm sorry if my question was confusingly worded, but Hynek is right. I was curious why `nosuspend` is not also used.

Comment: @troutwine: The answer is in `erlang:send_nosuspend/2` documentation. It works in different way. `noconnect` and `nosuspend` has a very little in common. `noconnect` works with connection. `nosuspend` works with overloading.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil Right, so the sending process suspends waiting for the receiving queue to have more headroom. Is it reasonable to believe, then, that the reason `gen_server` doesn't spawn a worker process here is so the system won't pile on further to an already overloaded queue?

Comment: @troutwine: No `gen_server` doesn't solve overloaded queue. `noconnect` is there to solve problem with disconnected nodes.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil Right, it's the `nosuspend` option I'm asking after. I get what `noconnect` is and why `gen_server` uses that option.

Comment: @troutwine: Read `erlang:send_nosuspend/2` documentation.

Comment: @rvirding Thanks very much for the edit and additional information.